# Python: Auto submit an input based on time?

Tags: python, input

Currently I am fiddling around with python and trying to make a snake game.
I have an input placed in a while loop which the player uses to move the snake around. The entire game works except the game only moves when the player presses enter. I was wondering if it were possible if I could have the input automatically press enter after x time.

Here's what I mean:

```
#variables
actionlast='w'
action='none'
actionlist=['w','a','s','d']

#input
action=input('Action: ')
if action in actionlist:
    actionlast=action
else:
    action=actionlast

#actions
if action == 'w':
    do blah blah

if action == 'a':
    do blah blah
```

So I want the input 'action' to automatically press enter every half second or so, and as you can see, if nothing is written in the input, it defaults to the last chosen action.

I hope this is clear enough for you all and I pray there is a solution :-)

Answer (score 0):

Write a function that is called by Python's [event scheduler](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sched.html). Within that function handle the user's input(s) and the computer's move. This makes your game process everything on a regular timer interval.

An alternative approach using a sleep function and [curses](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html) can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/sanchitgangwar/2158089).

Formore advanced gaming mechanisms, I'd recommend [PyGame](https://www.pygame.org/).

Comment: I can't figure out how to use the event scheduler. Could you please explain a little further?